# How to let user edit his first name and last name in Parse? Swift, Xcode 7

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

Hi I am a beginner at programming, I have Facebook hooked up with parse. all i want to know is how can a user edit his first name, last name.

Answer (score 0):

`PFQuery` the user information by their `currentUser.objectID` then just get their new `first name` and `last name` then override it in parse.

Comment: I added text fields where it will show the user's first name and last name but I don't know how to make it possible to save the changes the user makes. I created "Save" button but I don't know how to connect when button is clicked to save the changes made in the text field and then update it i parse. Can you please help me? I have this
if let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["first_name"] as? String {
            self.userFirst.text = pUserName         
            if let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["last_name"] as? String {
                self.userLast.text = pUserName